# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem uses ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In Asp.Net for creating a huge pdf report iam using "ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem", My requirement is report has to be created asynchronously , and i do not want to wait for the Response. I plan to achieve it through below code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(report => CreateReport());
}

public void CreateReport()
{
    //This method will take 30 seconds to finish it work
}
```

My question is  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem will create a new thread from Asp.Net worker process or some system thread. Is this a good approach ?, I may have 100 of concurrent users accessing the web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QueueUserWorkItem()` method utilizes the process's [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) which automatically manages a number of worker-threads.  These threads are assigned a task, run them to completion, then are returned to the ThreadPool for reuse.

Since this is hosted in ASP.NET the ThreadPool will belong to the ASP.NET process.

The ThreadPool is a very good candidate for this type of work; as the alternative of spinning up a dedicated thread is relatively expensive.  However, you should consider the following limitations of the ThreadPool as well:

- The ThreadPool is used by other aspects of .NET, and provides a limited number of threads.  If you overuse it there is the possibility your tasks will be blocked waiting for others to complete.  This is especially a concern in terms of scalability--however it shouldn't dissuade you from using the ThreadPool unless you have reason to believe it will be a bottleneck.
- The ThreadPool tasks must be carefully managed to ensure they are returned for reuse.  Unhandled exceptions or returns from a background thread will essentially "leak" that thread and prevent it from being reused.  In these scenarios the ThreadPool may effectively lose it's threads and cause a serious slowdown or halt of the process.
- The tasks you assign to the ThreadPool should be short-lived.  If your processing is intensive then it's a better idea to provide it with a dedicated thread.

All these topics relate to the simple concept that the ThreadPool is intended for small tasks, and for it's threads to provide a cost-saving to the consuming code by being reused.  Your scenario sounds like a reasonable case for using the ThreadPool--however you will want to carefully code around it, and ensure you run realistic load-tests to determine if it is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

The thread pool will manage the number of active threads as needed. Once a thread is done with a task it continues on the next queued task. Using the thread pool is normally a good way to handle background processing.

When running in an ASP.NET application there are a couple of things to be aware of:

- ASP.NET applications can be recycled for various reasons. When this happens all queued work items are lost.
- There is no simple way to signal back to the client web browser that the operation completed.

A better approach in your case might be to have a WCF service with a REST/JSON binding that is called by AJAX code on the client web page for doing the heavy work. This would give you the possibility to report process and results back to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Does it use Asp.Net thread / System Thread ?

Comment: The thread pool uses system threads internally but the advantage of using the pool is that you don't have to care how it is done. The thread management is provided in a black box. I assume that WCF uses the thread pool internally to handle requests, but it's the same there - you don't have to care. Just let the framework handle the threading complexity for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Anders Abel has already laid out, which I agree with entirely, you should consider that ASP.NET also uses the thread pool to respond to requests, so if you have long running work like this using up a thread pool thread, it is technically stealing from the resources which ASP.NET is able to use to fulfill other requests anyway.

If you were to ask me how best to architect it I would say you dispatch the work to a WCF service using one way messaging over the MSMQ transport. That way it is fast to dispatch, resilient to failure and processing of the requests on the WCF side can be more tightly controlled because the messages will just sit on the queue waiting to be processed. So if your server can only create 10 PDFs at a time you would just set the maxConcurrentCalls for the WCF service to 10 and it will only pull a maximum of 10 messages off the queue at once. Also, if your service shuts down, when it starts up it will just begin processing again.

Comment: I agree that WCF may be best way, But to get the technical facts right... "@anders Abel" responded Threadpool uses system threads (Not from ASP.Net resources) ? , but in your response you mentioned about asp.net uses same thread pool..