# Problems getting newly created thread to send outputs to asp:panel in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating a file processor for use in an intranet.
I described it in another question - [ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when processing a large number of files in ASP.Net using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128368/err-empty-response-when-processing-a-large-number-of-files-in-asp-net-using-c-sh)

Now, as suggested on above question's answer, I'm trying to use threads to execute the file processing task.

But there is a problem. I need the newly created thread to write feedbacks to a component in page (asp:panel, or div, or whatever). Those feedbacks would be results from several database operations.

The application reads those txts, interprets each line of it, and insert data in database. Each line inserted in database must return a feedback, like "registry 'regname' inserted successfully", or "i got problems inserting registry 'regname' in file 'filename', skipping to next registry".

I did test with something very simple:

```
protected void DoImport()
{
    try
    {
        MainBody.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "wait");

        int x = 0;
        while (x < 10000)
        {
            ReturnMessage(String.Format("Number {0}<hr />", x), ref pnlConfirms);
            x++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ReturnMessage(String.Format("<font style='color:red;'><b>FATAL ERROR DURING DATA IMPORT</b></font><br /><br /><font style='color:black;'><b>Message:</b></font><font style='color:orange;'> {0}</font><br />{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), ref pnlErrors);
    }
    finally
    {
        MainBody.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "default");
    }
}
```

This function is called from Page_Load, and fills an asp:panel called "pnlConfirms" with a row of numbers, but all at once, on load.

I changed it to:

```
protected void DoImport()
{
    try
    {
        MainBody.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "wait");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ReturnMessage(String.Format("<font style='color:red;'><b>FATAL ERROR DURING DATA IMPORT</b></font><br /><br /><font style='color:black;'><b>Message:</b></font><font style='color:orange;'> {0}</font><br />{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), ref pnlErrors);
    }
    finally
    {
        MainBody.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "default");
    }
}

private void DoWork(Object stateInfo)
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 10000)
    {
        ReturnMessage(String.Format("Number {0}<hr />", x), ref pnlConfirms);
        x++;
    }
}
```

And both uses this function:

```
public void ReturnMessage(string message, ref Panel panel, bool reset = false)
{
    if (reset)
    {
        panel.Controls.Clear();
    }
    Label msg = new Label();
    msg.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");
    msg.Text = message;
    panel.Controls.Add(msg);
}
```

I need `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork));` to fill those asp:panels with feedbacks - like insertion errors and warnings.

My code already has those feedbacks under `try...catch` statements, but they're not getting output to any asp:panel from threadpool (it works when invoked directly from `DoImport()` function, like in the first example I posted).

I'm doing something very wrong, but I can't find out what (and I'm researching this for almost 2 weeks). Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET, when a browser requests a page, that page is rendered and sent to the browser as soon as its processing finishes, so the browser will show the page as it's finally rendered.

According to your code you're trying to render a page, show a wait cursor, and expect it's shown on the browser and then, the cursor is changed by a default cursor. As I explained, independently from using or not additional threads, the page won't be sent to the browser until it's completely rendered. So you'l never see the wait cursor on the client side.

The easiest wait to get what you're trying to do is to use web services (traditional .asmx or WCF) and AJAX (jquery os ASP.NET AJAX).

1) create a web service that does the processing

2) create a page which is sent to the browser, and, using javascript (jQuery or ASP.NET AJAX) make a call to the web service, and show something to let the user know that the request is being processed. (a wait cursor, or even better an animated gif)

3) when the process finishes, your javascript will get the responde from the web service, and you can update the page to  let the user know the process has finished.

if you don't have experience on javascript, you can make most of this task using:

- [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) which can be used to [create a javascript web service proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx) for your client side ([other interesting article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx)) and is required for the rest of the controls
- some javascript (or jquery) which can be use to update the "process running/ process finished hints" on the client side. I.e. when the call to the web service ends, you can use javascript to update the page using DOM, or load a new page or the same page with an special parameter to show the result of the process

In this way you can do what you want:

1) show a page in a state that shows the process is running

2) show the same, or other page, in a state that shows the end of the process

The trick is comunicating the browser with the server, and this can only be done using some of the available ajax techniques.

Another typical technique is using jQuery.ajax, like [explained in encosia.com](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

According to the OP message, the process of all the files would be so slow that it would tiemout the web service call. If this is the case, you can use this solution:

1) Create a web service that process one (or a batch) of the pending files, and returns at least the number of pending files when it finishes the processing of the current file (or batch).

2) from the client side (javascript), call the web service. When it finishes, update the page showing the number of pending files, and, if this number is greater than zero, call the web service again.

3) when the call to the web service returns 0 pending files, you can update the page to show the work is finished, and don't call it any more.

If you process all the files at once, there will be no feedback on the client side, and there will also be a timeout. Besides, IIS can decide to stop the working thread which is making the work. IIS does this for several reasons.

A more reliable solution, but harder to implement, is:

1) implement a Windows Service, that does the file processing

2) implement a web service that returns the number of pending files (you can communicate the Windows Service and Web App indirectly using the file system, a database table or something like that)

3) use a timer (ajax timer, or javascript setInterval) from your web page to poll the server every N seconds using the web service, until the number of pending files is 0.

An even harder way to do this is hosting a WCF service in your Windows Service, instead of the indirect communication between your web app and windows service. This case is much more complicated because you need to use threads to do the work, and attend the calls to the wcf service. If you can use indirect communitacion it's much easier to implemente. The dtabse table is a simple and effective solution: your working process updates a row a table whenever it process a file, and the web service reads the progress state from this table.

There are many different soultions for a not so simple problem.

Comment: Yep. Ajax might be the way to do it. I was researching on doing this through JQuery. I'm quite experienced in JS, just need to make it work on ASP.Net.

The desired effect I want to make is to get the asp:panel filled dinamically with feedbacks sent by that thread while it is running... Would that be possible?

Comment: Well.. I'll clarify the main process:
The page shows a list of folders with txt files in it.
The user selects the folders he wants to process by marking each respective folder's checkbox, and click the "process" button.
Then, the page calls itself with parameters, and the Page_Load event checks those parameters. Then, it makes an array of folders (after checking them), and by loops under loops, it processes all files there. It opens each file and reads line by line. And breaks it in groups of characters to input into tables in a database. Each line is returned as error, warning or success.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get those returned messages into divs or panels in realtime, while processing?! Is it impossible to do it even by using ajax? Creating external services with indirect communication (by using timers) is too imprecise, and I can't see a way to get those messages... There gotta be another way :/

Comment: That would be possible if your web browser could listen notifications. But browsers can only ask and get a response (that's AJAX). That's why I propose polling or processing batches. Is it so important to get notified each time a file is processed? Consider that it's costly and unsafe to get info over the network: you can get it unordered, or even lose it. Indirect communitacion isn't a bad thing. You can create a row for each file to be processed in a table, and anytime a file is processed update it. Your Web Service can get all the info from it and send it to the browser: filename or whatevr

Comment: It is crucial to get notified. But well, I give up. I'll create a Windows Application to do the import job. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting new thread (or more precise running your code on one of free threads in thread pool)and not waiting for results in main thread. Something like Thread.Join (if you would use manual thread creation) or other synchronization mechanism as events need to be used if you want to go this route.

The question you've linked to suggests using asynchronous pages which you are not doing. You would start processing request, kick off the task and release the thread, when the task is finished you complete request.

Side note: consider simply doing all conversion on main thread that handles request. Unless you expect slow I/O to complete the task moving CPU work from one thread to another may not produce significant gains. Please measure performance of your current solution and confirm that it does not meet performance goals you have set up for your application. (this does not apply if you doing it for fun/educational purposes).

Comment: Well.. The conversion is a very heavy job, as I said on the other question... Processing 10.530 files just hangs the main thread.

Comment: Long running tasks in Web server is generally bad idea. But you should be able to convert your main request to async handler and send down updates for each file... Note that you'll have to expect partial updates of the result as you'll not be finishing request till all file are processed. Or better yet redesign your conversion framework to use some external process or restartable task of a sort and poll status from web page.